# Can't download file on ie10 using asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, download, content-type

I made a page where you are able to download files and it works fine in firefox and google chrome but when I do it in IE 10 i get a file with from the type "file" but it has to be pdf and I can't open it.

This is the code I use to download:

```
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & inhoud.titel & """")
        Response.BinaryWrite(inhoud.bestand)
        Response.End()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried appending `".pdf"` to the filename?

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & inhoud.titel & """" & ".pdf")
```